# How to minimize the length of the base64 string from nsdata of image?

Tags: ios, objective-c, encoding, base64, nsdata

I convert an image to NSData and NSData to base64string using

```
NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(imageView.image, 0.1f);
NSString *c = [NSString base64StringFromData:imagedata];
```

the fn for stringconversion

```
+ (NSString*)base64forData:(NSData*)theData {

    const uint8_t* input = (const uint8_t*)[theData bytes];
    NSInteger length = [theData length];

    static char table[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/=";

    NSMutableData* data = [NSMutableData dataWithLength:((length + 2) / 3) * 4];
    uint8_t* output = (uint8_t*)data.mutableBytes;

    NSInteger i;
    for (i=0; i < length; i += 3) {
        NSInteger value = 0;
        NSInteger j;
        for (j = i; j < (i + 3); j++) {
            value <<= 8;

            if (j < length) {
            value |= (0xFF & input[j]);
           }
        }

        NSInteger theIndex = (i / 3) * 4;
        output[theIndex + 0] =                    table[(value >> 18) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 1] =                    table[(value >> 12) & 0x3F];
        output[theIndex + 2] = (i + 1) < length ? table[(value >> 6)  & 0x3F] : '=';
        output[theIndex + 3] = (i + 2) < length ? table[(value >> 0)  & 0x3F] : '=';
    }

    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

but the resulted base64string is too long, its length is above 300000.
ie,

```
int len = c.length;
```

value of len is above 300000.

the image is of 3 to 4 mb
infact I compress the image to 0.1f

```
 NSData *imagedata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(iivv.image, 0.1f);
```

how to minimize the length, is there any other code for base64conversion from NSData?

Comment: Please use English numbering. Non-Asians are unlikely to be familiar with 'lakhs'. And what is '0.1f'? Furthermore, what makes you think the base64 string is "too long"?

Comment: 0.1f means compression fraction, according to that nsdata size will decrease

Comment: To be clear, what is the length of imageData and what is the length of your base64 string?

Comment: now Iam using an image of 2mb size, imagedata length=219499;base64length= 292668

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Base64 will always have larger space requirements than the original data, because it does not use all the bits in one byte. This is done intentionally in order to make sure that higher bits do not cause problems when being handed from one system to another. So in effect it trades space for transmission safety.

It is called Base64 because it only uses 6 bits (2^6=64) for each byte, therefore effectively taking up 5 bytes where the original data only had 4. Or put another way: size will increase by 25%.

The Base64 encoder of course does not care about what the bytes you feed into it represent, so you are free to compress the heck out of your data, as long as it is still in its own format (e. g. create a PNG or JPG out of uncompressed image data) and then encode that as Base64.

Comment: Actually, size of a base64 string should be about 137% of the original data (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME)

Comment: Oh, correct... I was writing this off the top of my head, but you get the idea :)

Comment: is there any way to minimize the size of imagedata

Comment: @NAZIK Not without reducing the quality of the JPEG. The point is that Base64 encoding will increase the size of your data by about 137% (which is what you have based on the numbers you provided in the comments on the question). There's no way around that. It's a fact of how Base64 encoding works. So the only way to reduce the Base64 size is to reduce the source data size which, in your case, means reducing the size of the JPEG which is done by setting the quality to a lower value. So use a lower value than 0.1f.

Comment: if I use lower than 0.1f the image quality will be more affecting, is this the only way?

Comment: if we directly convert the uiimage to base64 string, is it possible?

Comment: @NAZIK You can reduce the size dimensions of your image, but whatever you do, the image quality will suffer in some fashion. It takes a certain amount of data to represent a certain quality of image. The only way around it is magic...

Comment: @Pete: Nitpicking as you are: Not by about 137%, but BY 37% TO 137% :)